# Why is this counter assignment wrong?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am learning Verilog using the [HDLBits website](https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Popcount255), and I solved this problem (circuit counts the number of '1's in an input vector), but I want to understand why my previous tries were wrong.

**correct answer**

```
module top_module( 
    input [254:0] in,
    output [7:0] out );
    
    int i ;
    reg [7:0] counter;
    
    always @(*) begin 
        counter =0;
        for (i=0;i<255;i++)begin 
            counter = (in[i]==1)? counter+1:counter;
        end 
    out = counter ;
    end 
   

endmodule
```

**1st wrong answer**

```
module top_module( 
    input [254:0] in,
    output [7:0] out );
    
    int i ;
    reg [7:0] counter;
    
    always @(*) begin 
        counter =0;
        for (i=0;i<255;i++)begin 
            counter = (in[i]==1)? counter+1:counter;
        end 
    end 
    out = counter ;

endmodule
```

**2nd wrong answer**

```
module top_module( 
    input [254:0] in,
    output [7:0] out );
    
    int i ;
    
    
    always @(*) begin 
        out=0;
        for (i=0;i<255;i++)begin 
            out = (in[i]==1)? out+1:out;
        end 
    end 
    

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 3 code samples have syntax errors.  If the HDLBits website did not report errors, try the EDA Playground website simulators.

In your "correct" answer you need to change

```
output [7:0] out );
```

to:

```
output reg [7:0] out );
```

When you make an assignment to a signal inside an `always` block (a procedural assignment), you need to declare the signal as a `reg`.

In your "1st wrong answer", change:

```
out = counter ;
```

to:

```
assign out = counter ;
```

Continuous assignments (outside of `always` blocks) require the `assign` keyword.

In your "2nd wrong answer", use `reg` for `out`.